# VueJS activate boostrap modal from Javascript without the use of jQuery

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am working on an application using vuejs. When a user logins to my application, i would like to show an error (if any) using bootstrap modal instead of the old fashion alert. Is there a way to "pop" the modal from javascript without the use of jQuery?

Thank you :)

```
$("#loginerror").modal();
```

The code above uses jQuery but I do not want to use that.

I have tried using the ref method but it shows an error saying
this.$refs.loginerror.modal is not a function

Below is my code for the ref method:

```
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div ref="loginerror" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Login Error</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id = "loginerrormsg"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

snippets of Javascript code

```
.catch((error) => {
    document.getElementById("loginerrormsg").innerHTML = error;
    this.$refs.loginerror.modal();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Vuejs you should use refs, on your modal in the template set your reference for example:

```
<div ref="myModal">
</div>
```

and in your code you can activate it as follows:

```
this.$refs.myModal.modal();
```

This is the best way to access the DOM in vue

Comment: Hi @Sibelle thank you so much for your reply. I have tried following your method but it shows an error saying this.$refs.loginerror.modal is not a function. I have edited my post above together with my code for reference. Thank you

Comment: As mentioned in another answer the component itself does need jquery library even if you wont use it to toggle the modal, so you either have to import jquery as well or as mentioned upgrade to bootstrap 5 but my personal advise to you would be to use boostrapVue instead of just bootstrap and you wouldn't need any additional jquery it's better compatible with vuejs

Answer (score 2):

according to [bootstrap source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6ffb0b48e455430f8a5359ed689ad64c1143fac2/js/src/modal.js#L354-L366), this is how to hide modal.

```js
  _hideModal() {
    this._element.style.display = 'none'
    this._element.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true)
    this._element.removeAttribute('aria-modal')
    this._element.removeAttribute('role')
    this._isTransitioning = false
    this._showBackdrop(() => {
      $(document.body).removeClass(CLASS_NAME_OPEN)
      this._resetAdjustments()
      this._resetScrollbar()
      $(this._element).trigger(EVENT_HIDDEN)
    })
  }
```

it will change style display, aria-hidden, class name, and other stuff.

here is a simple reimplementation. may not work properly. but it does show and hide modal.

```js
const toggleModal = (modal) => {
  if (modal.classList.contains("show")) {
    modal.classList.remove("show");
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
  } else {
    modal.classList.add("show");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Bootstrap 4:
> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins.

So Bootstrap 4 required jQuery as dependency. If you still don't want to use jQuery in your application, you can migrate to Bootstrap 5.

Bootstrap 5 dropped jQuery dependency and is not required any more.

For more details on Bootstrap 5 you can visit: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/

For more details on Bootstrap 4 you can visit:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/